# How do I interpret this GADT error in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, gadt

Sorry about the "what am I missing here" style of question here, but I'm just missing something here.

I was trying to understand how GADTs work in OCaml, I define the following (in `utop`):

```
 type value =
| Bool : bool -> value
| Int : int -> value
;;

type _ value =
| Bool : bool -> bool value
| Int : int -> int value
;;

type _ expr =
| Value : 'a value -> 'a expr
| If : bool expr * 'a expr * 'a expr -> 'a expr
| Lt : 'a expr * 'a expr -> bool expr
| Eq : 'a expr * 'a expr -> bool expr
| Gt : 'a expr * 'a expr -> bool expr
;;
```

I defined an `eval` function:

```
let rec eval : type a. a expr -> a = function
| Value (Int i) -> i
| Value (Bool b) -> b
| Lt (a, b) -> (eval a) < (eval b)
| Gt (a, b) -> (eval a) > (eval b)
| Eq (a, b) -> (eval a) = (eval b)
| If (c, a, b) -> if eval c then (eval a) else (eval b)
;;
```

but got an error:

```
Line 4, characters 15-23:
Error: This expression has type $Lt_'a but an expression was expected of type
         int
```

**What exactly does this mean?**

Just to test further, I modified the expression GADT to be:

```
type _ expr =
| Value : 'a value -> 'a expr
| If : bool expr * 'a expr * 'a expr -> 'a expr
| Lt : int expr * int expr -> bool expr
| Eq : 'a expr * 'a expr -> bool expr
| Gt : int expr * int expr -> bool expr
;;
```

and then I see

```
Line 6, characters 15-23:
Error: This expression has type $Eq_'a but an expression was expected of type
         int
```

When I finally modify it to be

```
type _ expr =
| Value : 'a value -> 'a expr
| If : bool expr * 'a expr * 'a expr -> 'a expr
| Lt : int expr * int expr -> bool expr
| Eq : int expr * int expr -> bool expr
| Gt : int expr * int expr -> bool expr
;;
```

it works fine.

**Update (more context):**

- Ocaml version: `4.08.1`
- Libraries opened during this session: `Base`

**Update (solution):**

- it turned out to be (as mentioned in the first line of the selected answer) because I had previously, within `utop` run `open Base ;;`
- In a fresh session I'm able to enter the types initially mentioned and `eval` is happy with that.

Comment: Wait, is this because I use `<`, `>`, `=` in the evaluation, and these are restricted to `int` ?

Comment: I can't reproduce, on either 4.02.3 or 4.08.1. Which version are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct cause of the error is that you are using a library (maybe Base or Core?) that shadows the polymorphic comparison operators (`<`,`<=`,`=`,`>=`,`>`) and replace them with integer comparison operators.

Concerning the error message, when you pattern match a GADT constructor with existential types,

```
| Lt (a, b) -> (eval a) < (eval b)
```

the typechecker introduces new types to represent the existential types.
Here, in the (original) definition of `Lt`,

```
| Lt : 'a expr * 'a expr -> bool expr
```

there is one existentially quantified type variable: `'a`.

When pattern matching on `Lt`, we need to replace this type variable with
a new type. Moreover, it is quite useful in error message to try to pick
a meaningful name for this type. To do so, the typechecker constructs a
new type name piece by piece as `$` + `Lt` + `'a`:

- `$`: to mark an existential type
- `Lt`: to indicate that it was introduced by the constructor `Lt`
- `a`:  to remember that the existential type variable was named `'a` in the definition of the constructor

In other words, in the pattern match above, we have something akin to

```
| Lt ( (a: $Lt_'a eval), (b: $Lt_'a eval)) -> (eval a) < (eval b)
```

And when typing:

```
  (eval a) < (eval b)
```

the typechecker compare the type of `<`: `int -> int` with the type of `eval a`: `$Lt_'a` and outputs your original error message:

```
 Line 4, characters 15-23:
 Error: This expression has type $Lt_'a but an expression was expected of type
     int
```